# How can I near clip vertices in homogenous clip space (-w < xyz < w)?

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering, projection, clipping

I currently have a system in place to near clip vertices, but it only seems to work in view space.

The system is: Given a triangle, the near plane and the near plane normal, I check how many points are behind the clipping plane

If its 1: I create 2 new vertices at the intersections of the near plane, and reform triangles
If its 2: I create 1 new vertice at the intersection of the near plane, and reform triangle

But the problem is, when I try to use this system in homogenous clip space it doesen't work. I can't find the intersections, I don't know what the near plane is in homogenous clip space and I don't even know how to tackle the problem of all the vertices having different w values.

So what algorithm would I use to actually near clip triangles in homogenous clip space?

So far I've tried looking at many many articles to find this answer, but I find they don't give me answers that I am able to understand, instead just spouting loads and loads of math formulas.

Honestly I think this whole problem just stems from my lack of knowledge on 3D maths.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't even know how to tackle the problem of all the vertices having different w values.

Each vertex will need to check its `z` is more than or equal to (>=) its `-w` to make sure it is inside the near plane. If it is less than `-w`, it is outside.

If you have one vertex outside (`src`) and one vertex inside (`dst`) a plane, to find the clipped vertex (`clipped`) you interpolate (`t`) from `src`:

```
clipped = src + (dst-src) * t
```

t is the ratio of the signed distances of `src` and `dst` to the near plane.

In clip coordinates it can be calculated like this:

```
d1 = (src.z - (-src.w))
d2 = (dst.z - (-dst.w))
t = d1/(d1-d2)
```

I've written a software rasterizer in JavaScript that implements [clip space clipping here](https://github.com/andrew-lim/texturedemo/blob/master/clipspace.js).